# How to hover mutiple "div" in the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have

```
<div id="d1" class="hov"></div>
```

and

```
<div id="d2" class="hov"></div>
```

and the CSS is

```
.hov:hover{
    background-color:#cde0c4;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

When I hover on d1 I want d2 is hover same.
How to hover multiple DIVs at the same time?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, do you want to make both to show the *hover* state when one is hovered

Comment: could you also post the relevant markup? how are they related to each other? They share a common parent element?

Comment: I think, you cannot do that using CSS only, you need to use JS.

Comment: i want to use jquery to rise d2 hovered when i hovered on d1 but i can't find the solution to do that.

Comment: Like this? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/v1fem7hr/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need some Javascript for that. For instance:

```
document.body.addEventListener( 'mouseover', function( event ) {
    if( event.target.classList.contains( 'hov' ) ) {
        [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName( 'hov' ), function( elem ) {
            elem.classList.add( 'hover' );
        });
    }
});

document.body.addEventListener( 'mouseout', function( event ) {
    if( event.target.classList.contains( 'hov' ) ) {
        [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName( 'hov' ), function( elem ) {
            elem.classList.remove( 'hover' );
        });
    }
});
```

And you need to create a *css class* called `hover` which applies the same properties in this scenario.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/1LkfbcLx/

Comment: how about hovering the parent element?

Answer (score 4):

Could you wrap them both in a div?

```css
.container:hover .hov {
  background-color: #cde0c4;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="d1" class="hov">NUMBER 1</div>
    <br>
  <div id="d2" class="hov">NUMBER 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Kierans solution you can also do this with different classes if you would like.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

Then with CSS:

```
.container:hover .a,
.container:hover .b,
.container:hover .c {  
background-color:#cde0c4;
cursor:pointer; }
```

By doing this you avoid javascript for a simple task.
Example: [http://jsbin.com/nohawufoqa/1/edit?html,css,output]

Answer (score 0):

a quick dirty way would be to use script and some additional css. I havent tested it, but is should work

css:

```
.hov:hover, .active {
    background-color:#cde0c4;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

script:

```
$('#d1').hover( function() {
  $('.hov').addClass('active');
}, function() {
  $('.hov').removeClass('active');
});
```